# Visio web pages

Tags: javascript, visio

Visio allows you to save .vsd as .htm files.

I have a Visio web page diagram with diagram elements that contain URL links. I would like these links to contain the same URL parameters as the web page containing them.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like Microsoft Visio doesn't have any built-in support for anything like reading URL parameters, adding your own client-side Javascript interaction, or PHP server side scripting.

Right now it looks to me like the best thing to do is to hand edit the HTML versions, adding my own Javascript, and saving a backup of the file. This is because when Visio saves as a web page it overwrites my augments.

Is there a better way? Thanks